# Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell XPS 9360, WiFi stops working after about a day?

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, dell, xps

I have a Dell XPS 9360 from late 2017, and have recently fresh-installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Everything works perfectly, except that WiFi stops working after about 1-2 days of system uptime. The pizza-slice WiFi connection icon in the top right of the desktop goes from "perfect connection" to a question mark in the middle. Trying to run `sudo service network-manager restart` just freezes `sudo`, and I cannot `Ctrl+C` it... in this situation I have to do a hard shutdown by holding the power button for 5 seconds. My wireless card is:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       ...
```

I frankly don't know where to begin the debug process. Can anybody suggest what message logs I can look at/provide to try to diagnose and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No "software only" solution ended up working for me. What worked was to replace the WiFi card with the [Intel Wireless-Ac 9260](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079QH5KW1). I came upon this solution via the [Arch Linux docs for Dell XPS 9360](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9360)#Wireless).

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue with my new laptop. Two steps saved me from trouble:

- I installed latest kernel which is 5.9.15 at the time. Everything seems to be working fine so far.
- Then I added `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`
  and then reboot my machine.